# Lacie hard disk not found not found

Tags: disk

My computer doesn't recognize my hard disk Lacie. I have already used `sudo fdisk -l`, but my external hard disk is not in the list. The strange thing is that if I write `lsusb` this is the output:

`Bus 002 Device 006: ID 059f:1090 LaCie, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5d7 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 10c4:8108 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

So it seems that there is a Lacie somewhere....

When I go to search for disks, it shows me the Lacie, but I can see that there's no support.

What I have to do in this case?

0

I have now tried with : `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/usb* | grep sd`, and this is the output: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 lug 20 09:02 /dev/disk/by-id/usb-LaCie_P9227_Slim_0000NL376J7T-0:0 -> ../../sdb` , it seems that is it, but now, how can use this information?

I have also tried this: dmesg, it shows me those two errors: 
`[sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through`

With `lsblk` command it shows me only sda, but no sdb.

Now I'am trying: `dmesg | grep -i usb`

and this is the output: `[    0.244678] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.244678] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.244678] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.244678] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.279573] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.279599] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.279622] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.279862] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.281181] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 4.18
[    1.281183] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.281185] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.281187] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.281188] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.281373] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.282048] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.282051] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0  SuperSpeed
[    1.282092] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 4.18
[    1.282093] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.282095] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.282096] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.282097] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.282258] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.282467] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.616071] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.770436] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=8108, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    1.770437] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.770438] usb 1-1: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[    1.770439] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: YSPRINGTECH
[    1.900677] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.049185] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=e500, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    2.049186] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.176169] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.353208] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b5d7, bcdDevice=14.07
[    2.353209] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    2.353210] usb 1-8: Product: EasyCamera
[    2.353211] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
[    2.353212] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 0x0001
[    2.360038] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.360039] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.361300] input: YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:10C4:8108.0001/input/input3
[    2.361357] hid-generic 0003:10C4:8108.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [YSPRINGTECH USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[   23.102147] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   26.364286] input: EasyCamera: EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input7
[   26.364336] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   26.364337] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[  540.419079] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  540.439983] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1090, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  540.439989] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  540.439993] usb 2-3: Product: P9227 Slim
[  540.439996] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: LaCie
[  540.439999] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 0000NL376J7T
[  540.568414] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  540.581313] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  611.235233] usb 2-3: cmd cmplt err -71
[  611.975752] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 2298.733074] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2298.887392] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2237, idProduct=4225, bcdDevice= 1.10
[ 2298.887399] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2298.887402] usb 1-3: Product: eReader-4.5.9587
[ 2298.887406] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Kobo
[ 2298.887409] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: N709680008759
[ 2298.894193] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2298.894979] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 2366.427380] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 2393.507874] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2393.529078] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1090, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 2393.529084] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 2393.529088] usb 2-3: Product: P9227 Slim
[ 2393.529091] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: LaCie
[ 2393.529094] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 0000NL376J7T
[ 4644.776572] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 4659.517859] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 4659.539042] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1090, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 4659.539048] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 4659.539052] usb 2-2: Product: P9227 Slim
[ 4659.539055] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: LaCie
[ 4659.539058] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 0000NL376J7T
[ 4668.693905] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 4680.110034] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4680.131104] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1090, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 4680.131109] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 4680.131113] usb 2-2: Product: P9227 Slim
[ 4680.131116] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: LaCie
[ 4680.131118] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 0000NL376J7T
[ 4701.646045] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 4753.686126] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 4753.707418] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=059f, idProduct=1090, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 4753.707424] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 4753.707428] usb 2-3: Product: P9227 Slim
[ 4753.707431] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: LaCie
[ 4753.707434] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 0000NL376J7T`

And the end there is Lacie and it says "New Usb device found".

Now that I'am seeing this code I can notice that there are many usb, but he says that they are all disconnected. But Lacie is connected with usb cable.

Now I use this command: `ls /dev | grep sd`

this is the output: `sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sda4
sda5
sda6
sdb`

Lacie must be the sdb one.

I'am searching for the error, now I see that I can't open sdb and this is the error message: `The super-blocco could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
file system.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
file system (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the super-blocco
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate super-blocco:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>`

So, as I understand, it can't read the super-block sdb.

Now I see that there is an error of input/output for my device Lacie.

Fo solving the super-block I have tried this command: `sudo su
for count in 1 2 3 4; do mkdir /mnt/sdb$count; mount /dev/sdb$count /mnt/sdb$count; done
exit`

This is the output: `/mnt/sdb$count; mount /dev/sdb$count /mnt/sdb$count; done
mount: /mnt/sdb1: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist.
mount: /mnt/sdb2: special device /dev/sdb2 does not exist.
mount: /mnt/sdb3: special device /dev/sdb3 does not exist.
mount: /mnt/sdb4: special device /dev/sdb4 does not exist.`

It seems that my Lacie for my computer does not exist, even if it is connected and it lighten.

Things get worst: I'am listening to a bad noise from my Lacie.

I'am hiking that it is searously damaged the Lacie, the bip seems to show that there are physical damages.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question (it's easier to read, can be edited & has better formatting options).  I prefer `lsblk`(*list block devices*) myself to get information about drives pre-mounting - but your comment is hard to read.

Comment: I tried lsbk but it does not show the sdb I'am serching for. It only show a sda, wich is the memory of my computer and not the extenral one.  I have reposted the comment below with some new informations.

Comment: External hard drive and usb3.. See if this helps:
`# echo "options usb-storage quirks=059f:1090:u" >> /etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage-quirks.conf`
`# update-initramfs -u`
And then reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue with a **Lacie d2 Quadra USB 3.0**. Worked fine if connected to a Windows PC, but not so much with Ubuntu (22.04).

Luckily, the d2 Quadra has an `eSATA` connector. This interface seems to be kind of rare these days, at least in the "office environment". So I bought [one of these USB-to-eSATA converters](https://www.startech.com/en-us/hdd/usb3c2esat3) - ***works perfectly!*** Problem solved.